# Does max SQL memory include SQL AG memory requirements?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, sql-server-2019

I have sql server 2019 enterprise on windows server 2019, with 30 databases totalling 500GB size. RAM is 100GB.

Of this 94GB is allocated as Max sql server memeory.

So 6GB remains for OS.

There is windows cluster and AG setup for 15 databases. I believe that memory for the cluster and AG are separate from the 94GB max sql memory setting. Is there any guide to estimate how much memory cluster and AG require?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that memory for the cluster and AG are separate from the 94GB max sql memory setting.

For AG memory would come from max server memory. [SQL Server max server memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/memory-management-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#dynamic-memory-management) controls

> The SQL Server memory allocation, compile memory, all caches (including the buffer pool), query execution memory grants, lock manager memory, and CLR1 memory (essentially any memory clerk found in sys.dm_os_memory_clerks).
> CLR memory is managed under max_server_memory allocations starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x).  Memory for thread stacks, heaps, linked server providers other than SQL Server, or any memory allocated by a “non SQL Server” DLL is not controlled by max server memory.

So for some Windows cluster DLL's the memory may come from OS but that would be very less and you should hardly bother about that.

In your case if this is dedicated SQL Server instance leave 7-8 GB for OS and assign rest to SQL Server. Monitor memory usage by following counters.

- Total Server memory
- Target Server memory
- Database memory
- Page Life expectancy of NUMA nodes( if you have)
- Buffer Manager: Free Pages
- Memory Manager: Memory grants pending.

PS: You are asking lot of questions answer to which can easily be found by little searching. I strongly suggest you to read books online.

Comment: The link you have references says `CLR memory is managed under max_server_memory allocations starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x).` then further down it says `Memory for thread stacks1, CLR2, extended procedure .dll files, the OLE DB providers referenced by distributed queries, automation objects referenced in Transact-SQL statements, and any memory allocated by a non SQL Server DLL are not controlled by max server memory.` - 1st thing says `managed` and 2nd thing says `not controlled`. What does this mean?

Comment: Cluster is a windows feature and AG is a SQL feature - I'm not sure on what basis you are saying that this is part of the max sql memory. Any reference links will be helpful.

Comment: I also wrote `So for some Windows cluster DLL's the memory may come from OS but that would be very less and you should hardly bother about that`. Did u not read that ? This is NOT documented anywhere AFAIK. WSFC memory requirements here would be very less as compared to SQL Server and AG. So I would not bother about it.

Comment: Managed and not controlled are same, its basically 2 people using diff word to describe same feature. I have updated my answer to reflect things more correctly

Comment: 1st statement says CLR mem is managed under max server mem allocation. 2nd statement says memory for CLR is not controlled by max server memory. How is that the same thing? Aren't they contradictory.

Comment: Also this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15#manually) says 25% must be allocated to buffer pool, etc `Then subtract 25% for other memory allocations outside the max server memory control, such as backup buffers....`

Comment: CLR is managed by max server memory period. *BOL has slightly inaccurate*, if you read below it says `2 CLR memory is managed under max_server_memory allocations starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x).`  Before that it was out of max server memory. Again for 25% you are reading it like immature. This is reason precisely your questions are being downvoted.

Comment: And how are you implying that SQL AG is related to the SQL CLR?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136422/discussion-between-shanky-and-variable).

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that memory for the cluster and AG are separate from the 94GB max sql memory setting

Yes and no. Windows Failover Clustering is OS-level feature that is absolutely separate from the DBMS. So here you are correct, this part is not covered by 'max server memory' of SQL Server, though the memory consumption is negligible.

Talking about the Always On, for its operation you need one worker thread in Primary Replica for log change capture, and additional one per each Secondary Replica you send data to. On a secondary replica it is just one worker thread per database for REDO process.

For 64-bit systems one worker thread uses 2 MB of memory.

```
So, for your 15 databases it would be = 15 databases x 2 workers x 2 MB = 60 MB.
```

It is not a lot, and yes, the Worker Pool is covered by 'max server memory' setting.

Though, from my experience if you have over 300 databases and several replicas, you may get several gigabytes of RAM that is being used only to support Always On functioning. And usually you exceed the number of worker threads available by default.

> Is there any guide to estimate how much memory cluster and AG require?

I do recommend the following reading:

[Memory management architecture guide](https://Memory%20management%20architecture%20guide)
[Configure the max worker threads (server configuration option)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16)
[Max Worker Threads for SQL Server Always on Availability Group databases](https://www.sqlshack.com/max-worker-threads-for-sql-server-always-on-availability-group-databases/)

To be honest, I do not know you workload but 15 databases is not a big deal for Always On, it can easy grind times more with 100 GB of RAM.

Probably, if you have any memory leak, you need to look somewhere else.